# Webpack progress using node.js API

Tags: webpack

Is there currently a way to access webpack's progress while using the node.js API? I'm familiar with the --progress flag using the CLI.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Webpack CLI uses the [ProgressPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ProgressPlugin.js) to log the progress of a compilation.

```js
var ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');

var compiler = webpack(config);

compiler.apply(new ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
  console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
}));

compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
  // ...
});
```

Here is a link to the [Compiler documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#compiler) and the [ProgressPlugin documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/internal-webpack-plugins#progresspluginhandler).

Comment: Pair this with [node-progress](https://github.com/tj/node-progress) for formatted console output.

Comment: List of all internal Webpack plugins: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/internal-webpack-plugins

Comment: According to the latest Webpack changes you should replace:
`compiler.apply(new ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
  console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
}));` with `new ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
  console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
}).apply(compiler);`

Answer (score 16):

To output something similar as the CLI `--progress` flag:

```js
    var webpack = require('webpack')
    var ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin')
    var config = require('./webpack.config')
    var compiler = webpack(config)

    compiler.apply(new ProgressPlugin(function (percentage, msg, current, active, modulepath) {
      if (process.stdout.isTTY && percentage < 1) {
        process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
        modulepath = modulepath ? ' …' + modulepath.substr(modulepath.length - 30) : ''
        current = current ? ' ' + current : ''
        active = active ? ' ' + active : ''
        process.stdout.write((percentage * 100).toFixed(0) + '% ' + msg + current + active + modulepath + ' ')
        process.stdout.clearLine(1)
      } else if (percentage === 1) {
        process.stdout.write('\n')
        console.log('webpack: done.')
      }
    }))

    compiler.run(function (err, stats) {
      if (err) throw err
      process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
        colors: true,
        modules: false,
        children: false,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false
      }) + '\n\n')
    })
```

Comment: In Webpack 5, this results in `TypeError: compiler.apply is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-bar-webpack-plugin this plugin leverages node-progress.

```
  new ProgressBarPlugin({
    format: '  build [:bar] :percent (:elapsed seconds)',
    clear: false, 
    width: 60
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is six years old!!! but also, if you're using bash or any term supporting ANSI/VT100 escape codes ...

```
handler(percentage, message, ...args) { 
  console.info(`\u001b[A\u001b[K\u001b[33m${(percentage * 100).toFixed(2)}%`+
    `\t\u001b[0m\u001b[1m${message}\t`+
    `\u001b[0m\u001b[90m${args && args.length>0?args[0]:""}\u001b[0m`);
}
```

(handler function of ProgressPlugin from Webpack 5.x)

Prints it in same line, with percentage in yellow, message in default console color, and first arg if any in dark grey.

[image: print out sample]

More about escape ANSI chars for bash or ANSI/VT100 compatible term:
https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Now, let's go to code important stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

I see the answers here are a few years old, so took a closer look myself at how the webpack cli is doing it, and tried it myself. This works for me on webpack 5.74, node 16.15.1

```js
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const config = require('./path/to/webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);

new ProgressPlugin({
  profile: true
}).apply(compiler);

compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
//handle outputting errors as you like here
});
```

Taken from https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/packages/webpack-cli/src/plugins/CLIPlugin.ts#L48-L50

Answer (score 0):

for webpack@^5.65.0 using below

```
/**
 * gulp webpack build production using NodeJS API
 * @param {<T>(err?: null | Error, result?: T) => any} done
 */
const buildProduction = done => {
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const config = require('./config/webpack.prod');
  const merge = Object.assign(config, { mode: 'production' });
  // add --progress args to webpack
  merge.plugins.push(new webpack.ProgressPlugin());
  // same as yarn build:webpack
  const compiler = webpack(merge);

  compiler.run(function (err, stats) {
    if (err) throw err;
    process.stdout.write(
      stats.toString({
        colors: true,
        modules: false,
        children: false,
        chunks: false,
        chunkModules: false
      }) + '\n\n'
    );

    compiler.close(done);
  });
};
```