# How to run webpack with certain options from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I currently have a package.json file that includes this script:

```
"build": "webpack --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached",
```

I also have a webpack.config.js at the root of my repository.

I'm trying to make my npm scripts less verbose by moving them to separate .js files. I've done some simple ones (clean with rimraf and a simple copy), but I'm struggling with calling webpack from a (node) javascript file. This is what I've tried:

```
// contents of ./build/compile.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');

webpack(webpackConfig);
```

This does nothing. I've also tried:

```
// contents of ./build/compile.js
var webpack = require('webpack');

webpack({
    inline: true,
    colors: true,
    // and so on
});
```

This also does nothing. Just calling `webpack()` also does nothing...

And by nothing, I mean it also doesn't throw an error.

So how can I call webpack, make it use my config file, but also pass along the flags like `--inline --colors --progress ...`?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html ? I believe you'll have to implement some of the features of the CLI yourself, since `webpack(...)` by itself won't generate any output afaik. Or spawn a child process instead. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at the node api, but didn't find what I was looking for. I guess it isn't entirely possible, except by spawning a child process as you mention. If you put that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding progress, this answer worked for me..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069781

```
var ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin')

var compiler = webpack(cfg)
compiler.apply(new ProgressPlugin((percentage, msg) => {
    console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
 }))

 compiler.run((err, stats) => {
     if (err) return reject(err);
     resolve(stats)
 })
```

Comment: from where do you know "reject" and "resolve" in your example?